# Check for loading spinner or content in Python Playwright

Tags: python, playwright

I have a React app that fetches data from an API, and I'm building out tests with Python Playwright.

My problem is that in situations where the UI is the result of an API call, there are three possible states:

- Loading
- Error message
- Success (unknown number of elements)

I'm trying to find an elegant way to check for the various states.

[From the docs](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-frame#frame-wait-for-load-state), apparently it's not recommended to wait until the network is idle, so I need a way to check for when the loading spinner has been cleared and either check for the error message or start iterating over the loaded content locators.

This seems like a common use case, but I can't find much in the way of recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

This should help in waiting for spinner to disappear(JS):

```
await expect(spinnerLocator).toHaveCount(0);
```

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/11988

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help to wait spinner locator disappearance:

```
await spinnerLocator.waitFor({ state: 'hidden' });
```

But at first you should be ensure that spinner was appeared after executing an action which causes this. You can do it by using `Promise.all` statement, e.g. like here:

```
await Promise.all([
  spinnerLocator.waitFor({ state: 'visible' }), // start awaiting of the spinner appearance
  yourActionWhichCausesSpinnerAppearance(), // execute an action which causes spinner appearance
]);

// wait for spinner disappearance
await spinnerLocator.waitFor({ state: 'hidden' });
```

Comment: This is helpful, I can adapt it for use in Python. I'm not using the async API, that might make this issue easier to resolve. thanks.